# DnD 5e what's best for my stats as a paladin?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, paladin, ability-scores

I rolled 17, 17, 15, 15, 13 and an 8. I'm also human (non variant), so currently I assigned my stats as follows:
**Str:** 18
**Dex** 9
**Con:** 16
**Int:** 14
**Wis:** 16
**Char:** 18

My plan was to +2 to both Str and Char, to max 20, +1 to dex (10) and to con (17), take feat resilient (con- 18) and wis to 18. Getting rid of that neg modifier for dex will be for my first ASI. But I'm not sure whether I should keep wisdom at 16 and raise dex to a 12. I know switching 14 dex and 9 intel would be better against checks, but for roleplaying purposes, I need my intelligence decent enough. Rather than resilient, I might take the inspiring leader feat for the group. I'm also looking to take the Oath of Ancient's feature, and I'm likely to take a supportive/tank role, but I like to deal out reasonable damage and hold my own if need be. The rest of my party is 2 fighters, 1 druid, a warlock and sorcerer. Currently, I have two swords for my character, but thinking of switching to shield and sword. Will be taking Dueling fighting style.

This is the first I'm playing DnD (and the same for 4 of us) so build thoughts would be great. Specifically, though, what's best to assign the ASI stats to, or choose feats, if I want to be good at protecting allies and surviving (with decent damage/killing efficiency)? Which out of the following set-ups would be a fit?

Plan 1

**1st ASI:** dex + 1 (10), con +1 (17)
**2nd ASI**: char + 2 (20)
**3rd ASI:** Resilient Feat con +1 (18)
**4th ASI:** Inspiring Leader or Sentinel or Shield Master or Mounted Combat (coupled with use of Fine Steed), or stre +2
**5th ASI:** stre + 2 or Inspiring Leader, Sentinel or Shield Master or Mounted Combat (coupled with use of Fine Steed)

Plan 2:
same as above but 1st ASI increase char to 20, and 2nd ASI increase dex and con.

Sorry if that's messy, I've just been looking around at Paladin guides but haven't found anything useful with high stats, and don't generally know what I need mechanically beyond strength and charisma and good con.

Comment: I know just the build for a high stats paladin. Unfortunately, as the question is on-hold and unclear what you mean by best, I can't answer. Maybe you can clarify what "best" means for you. Do you want to do the most damage? Get the best defense? protect your allies? even be the best at talking? what do you want to be "best" at?

Comment: We don't have a cleric, so I will likely be doing the healing. So best at protecting allies, but also 'leading' aka talking. I don't want to sacrifice damage much though, because as a player I don't like not being able to handle my own. I'm /used/ to doing the most damage, but given the two fighters it won't be my primary role.

Comment: Due to the revision history we have here on RPG.SE, [please don't signal your edits](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). It's better to rewrite the question, since we can all look back on the edits and see what was changed.

Comment: See [this meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1641/23970) for guidance on what makes a character-building good sometimes, bad some other times. (I'm not implying yours falls in either direction--just wanted to link you and future readers to that excellent guidance.) Yours would seem to fall into the second category listed.

Comment: Hey @Heda, sorry but I am voting to close this as too broad. If you have something specific about your build that you'd like help with, you can edit your question. But, if you're looking for _general_ advice, you might be better suited to a [forum, here's a list that this site recommends](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23064). There's another recourse you can also resort to, and that's by joining us in [chat], you can view it for free but you'll need 20 rep to participate. As such, I have +1ed your answer to give you 5, 2 more upvotes and you can ping me in chat by typing "@daze413"

Comment: Are you playing 20th level characters or are you starting out at 1st?  I ask because I've not seen anyone actually plan out their ability gains like this all the way up.

Comment: Starting at 1st level. Do people not usually plan the direction they want to build their characters? I know plans can change during the campaign, but I figure an idea is nice, or knowing the better options. Like if someone else will be taking inspiring leader, then I certainly won't. Anyone have an idea to narrow this more than what it already is (best picking plan 1 with feat/s x, or plan 2 with feat/s x)? I'm thinking I might have to take this to a forum